# Knee acting weird in walking animation

Tags: animation, rigging

So I got my rig set up right so it doesn't glitch. But now I'm having a weird problem with the knee in the walking animation. If you open the copy of my blend file and run it from frames 40-60 you will see that I move the foot forward at those key frames. Now when the knee moves between 40 and 60 I fully extends straight then bends again in those ten frames. The two key frames don't shift the knee so the leg should go straight so why does the knee do that for a second between the two key frames at 40 and 60?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean, but I think the main problem in your walk is that your *Hips* bone is much too high at frame 40 and 60, which makes your walk not good at all: when the legs spread, it's like the low of the walk sinusoid, the hips are supposed to lower down much more, and thus make the knee bend more naturally, perhaps that's the problem you're talking about?

[image]